# Form Creation and Validation in Slim Framework

Tags: api, slim

I gonna develop a form using slim framework. I know we can develop REST API's using SLIM.  I need to know whether we can design forms and validate those.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slim doesn't give you these kind of utils. You could use external libraries to validate forms like [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) or you could use [rapyd-framework](https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-framework) (**Notice that its development is now stopped**),

> a microframework built on top of Slim Framework, Twig, Symfony Forms,
>   Illuminate/Database, Twitter Bootstrap

that supports Symfony Forms.